# force close app when battery is low

Tags: android, power-management

I'm coding for app,where i just want add a feature i.e when battery level is getting low(say for less than 20%),app will automatically get stopped and respective services also get closed ,is it possible?if so please give some methods to do so..Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be possible but you may want to rethink this. If it just closes, your users may think its a bug. Before it gets to the critical point, you may want to warn the users instead

Comment: @codeMagic ya i will surely show a alert about the battery status,but is it possible to make app terminate itself?

Comment: Of course you can just finish any open `Activities`. I don't know what you have going on but just keep track of any running services that you need to stop or anything like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to the `Intent` `"android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"` with an `BroadcastReciever`

You can stop your components via:
Add the `BroadcastReceiver` via code in your `Services` and `Activities`. It will receive the `Intent` where you can stop the components: `Activity` has `finish()`, `Service` has `stopSelf()`.
This will only stop the components which have been running before! (a good thing)

Or you can do it via `BroadcastReceiver` via `manifest`:
When you receive it in the `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` you can call `stopService` to stop your Service. To stop the `Activity` is a lot harder, check if your `Activity` is in the foreground, send a custom Intent to it. It will receive it and can stop itself. Prerequisite is that it is `singleInstance`.